# Go and Object Oriented Paradigm

Tags: go

Given the following interface...

```
type Person struct {
    name, gender string
}

type Citizen interface {
    Create(name string) Citizen
    GetName() string
    GetGender() String
    SayHello() String
}
```

... and the following `Male` and `Female` implementations:

```
type Male Person

func (m *Male) Create(name) Citizen {
    return &Person{name, "male"}
}

func (m *Male) GetName() string {
    return m.name
}

func (m *Male) GetGender() string {
    return m.gender
}

func (m *Male) SayHello() string {
    return "Hello (male voice)"
}

type Female Person

func (f *Female) Create(name) Citizen {
    return &Person{name, "female"}
}

func (f *Female) GetName() string {
    return f.name
}

func (f *Female) GetGender() string {
    return f.gender
}

func (m *Female) SayHello() string {
    return "Hello (female voice)"
}

func main() {
    var p1 Person = &Male{}
    var p2 Person = &Female{}

    p1 = p1.Create("Joe")
    p2 = p2.Create("Heidi")

    log.Printf("%s is a %s",p1.GetName(), p1.GetGender())
    log.Printf("%s says %s",p1.GetName(), p1.SayHello())
    log.Printf("%s is a %s",p2.GetName(), p2.GetGender())
    log.Printf("%s says %s",p2.GetName(), p2.SayHello())
}
```

As only `Create` is gender-specific, is there a way to let `Male` and `Female` inherit a common implementation of methods `GetName` and `GetGender`?

Comment: a) *there is no inheritance in Go*; and b) constructors should not be part of the interface of the type they construct, they should be functions (not methods).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embed `Person` in the `Male` and `Female` types and push the base methods up to `Person`.

```
type Male struct {
    Person
}

type Female struct {
    Person
}

func (m *Person) GetName() string {
    return m.Name
}

func (m *Person) GetGender() string {
    return m.Gender
}

func main() {
    var c Citizen
    c = CreateMale("Joe")
    fmt.Println(c.GetName(), c.GetGender(), "\n", c.SayHello())
    c = CreateFemale("Jane")
    fmt.Println(c.GetName(), c.GetGender(), "\n", c.SayHello())
}
```

See full example here: https://play.golang.org/p/GZcG-n_YpM

This uses the interface `Citizen` instead of the type `Person` in the assignment, so let me know if that isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: OK, you removed the `Create` method from the interface and put the rest in the `Person`implementation... but what if the interface has another method (i.e. `SayHello`) that is gender-specific?

Comment: @j3d it's exactly the same. Updated answer to add a `SayHello` method. I only removed `Create` because it didn't seem useful to have to create a blank person to call the `Create` method on. I can add it back in if you wish

Comment: Ok, it's clear now :-) Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: @j3d This includes the male/female `Create` method if you wish to keep it. https://play.golang.org/p/mnUWaFNxWT

Comment: Actually, leaving the `Create` method does a whole lot more harm than good... well actually it does no good and only harms the interface.

Comment: Just a note: `GetX` is against conventions. The convention is `X()` for getters and `SetX( x typeOfX)` for setters.